# How to return byte data with Android's ParcelFileDescriptor and Documents Provider

Tags: java, android

I'm building a [Documents Provider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/create-document-provider) in order to access data that my application has, which I am able to represent as a byte array. I have gotten the querying working, but I have become stuck on the opening as I do not fully understand how the ParcelFileDescriptor works and how I am able to pass data through it.

When my document provider's `openDocument` is called, I get a byte array representing my file data.

```
private ParcelFileDescriptor getFileDescriptor(byte[] data) throws IOException {
    ParcelFileDescriptor[] pipes = ParcelFileDescriptor.createReliablePipe();
    ParcelFileDescriptor readPipe = pipes[0];
    ParcelFileDescriptor writePipe = pipes[1];

    OutputStream stream = new ParcelFileDescriptor.AutoCloseOutputStream(writePipe);
    stream.write(data);
    return writePipe;
}
```

Then, in my activity, I receive the `uri` and to open I run:

```
try {
    InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    int c;
    while ((c = reader.read()) != -1) {
        stringBuilder.append(c);
    }
    reader.close();
    String fileData = stringBuilder.toString();
    textView.setText(uri.toString() + "\n\n" + fileData);
} catch (IOException e) {
    textView.setText(uri.toString() + "\n\nError: " + e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I believe this should allow me to pull out that data, but I am getting the error `java.io.IOException: read failed: EBADF (Bad file descriptor)`

If I try returning the `readPipe` in my method, the app appears to get in a bad state and stops working. So, I think returning the `writePipe` is what I want, but I don't know why it can't be read. I haven't had luck finding a good example of using a `ParcelFileDescriptor` in this way.

Thanks.

Comment: [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.13/ContentProvider/Pipe) is for a `ContentProvider`, not specifically a `DocumentsProvider`, but the same principle for working with a `ParcelFileDescriptor` pipe should hold.

Comment: Thanks for that. Looking at that example was helpful.

Answer (score 3):

After looking at the example that came from @CommonsWare, I was able to determine how to manage the pipes in order to process my byte array and then return that to the calling activity.

Here's how the code ultimately turned out.

```
private ParcelFileDescriptor getFileDescriptor(byte[] fileData) throws IOException {
    Log.d(TAG, "Found " + fileData.length + " bytes of data");
    ParcelFileDescriptor[] pipe = ParcelFileDescriptor.createPipe();

    // Stream the file data to our ParcelFileDescriptor output stream
    InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileData);
    AutoCloseOutputStream outputStream = new AutoCloseOutputStream(pipe[1]);
    int len;
    while ((len = inputStream.read()) >= 0) {
        outputStream.write(len);
    }
    inputStream.close();
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();

    // Return the ParcelFileDescriptor input stream to the calling activity in order to read
    // the file data.
    return pipe[0];
}
```

Comment: You read and write bytes one by one. That makes transfer slow. Better use a buffer.

Comment: Thanks. This snippet is definitely better than the app crashing, but adding something like a buffer would probably be much more efficient.

Comment: Doing it on a worker thread would help too but this is enough for demo.